# what is the output of a $ some string in scala

Tags: scala

I am working with spark and scala and saw the following in the online docs

```
df.select($"name", $"age" + 1).show()
```

What does $"name" mean here?

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other.

Comment: They're both literally asking what the `$` symbol does, and _both_ make the misunderstanding that it's Scala syntax as opposed to a Spark method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`$` in your example is not a scala thing.

```
scala> val name = "something"
name: String = something

scala> println($"name")
<console>:12: error: value $ is not a member of StringContext
       println($"name")
               ^
```

Rather `$` is from spark framework, which [represents a column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html).

See the [org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L42) code over here,

```
  implicit class StringToColumn(val sc: StringContext) {
    def $(args: Any*): ColumnName = {
      new ColumnName(sc.s(args: _*))
    }
  }
```

You could simply do `dataframe.select("columnname").show` or `dataframe.select(col("columnname")).show` too, but `dataframe.select($"columnname")` to mutate the column value, like you are incrementing age in your example.

eg.

Given a dataframe,

```
 +----+-------+
 | age|   name|
 +----+-------+
 |null|Michael|
 |  30|   Andy|
 |  19| Justin|
 +----+-------+

scala> dataframe.select($"name".as('myname)).show()
+-------+
| myname|
+-------+
|Michael|
|   Andy|
| Justin|
+-------+

scala> dataframe.select("age"+1).show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`age1`' given input columns: [age, name];;
'Project ['age1]
```

Other example to use `$` could be filter based on column values,

```
dataframe.filter($"age" > 28).show()
```

So, basically, you are making it a variable(of type `Column`) with `$""` in Spark.

### NOTE:

Scala has `${}` while concatenating the variables, (aka `String interpolation`)

```
scala> val printMe = "prayagupd"
printMe: String = prayagupd

scala> println(s"value = $printMe")
value = prayagupd
```

Comment: Superb explanation. Thank you so much